# For a Crystal Report, I need to formulate a comparison of data from last month to same date in current month

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I need to see all loans that closed last month up to this same date in current month.  So, if today is 3/13/2012, I want to count loans closed 2/1 through 2/13/2012 to compare volume between months.  How do I write that date formula?  It's similar to the LastYearMTD date range option, but I really only want LastMonthTD for a range.

Answer (score 1):

The dateserial() function handles all the messiness of adding/subtracting dates. To get the date range you're after:

`dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,1) to
dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)-1,day(currentdate))`

Comment: that doesn't handle the scenario where currentdate is in january :)

Comment: @LeeTickett Yes it does. DateSerial() handles that logic. It also handles date subtraction/addition spilling over months, years, weeks, etc.

Comment: ah- so it does. though i think the question hasn't been worded brilliantly- and the poster is asking for figures for loans closed during 1st of this month to date and 1st of last month to date-1month

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this...

Selection criteria:

```
{loans.closedate} > dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)
or
{loans.closedate} in 
 dateadd('m', -1, dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate),1)) to 
 dateadd('m', -1, currentdate)
```

Then your closed last month tally would be:

```
if month({loans.closedate}) = month(currentdate) then
 1
else
 0
```

And the closed this month tally would be the other way around:

```
if month({loans.closedate}) = month(currentdate) then
 0
else
 1
```

No doubt this could be simplified.